# What is best practice for writing object in javascript and react

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I have some examples when I write object, It's very hard to select what the best practice(coding style) is.

```js
//destructuring single property
const {foo} = this.state;
const { foo } = this.state;

//destructuring multi properties
const {foo, bar} = this.state;
const { foo, bar } = this.state;

//declaration and initialize single object
const obj = {foo: 'foo'}
const obj = { foo: 'foo' }
const obj = {
    foo: 'foo'
}
```

#### p.s.

I know, my question is quite far from the real coding problem.
but I want to know what the better idea for beautify code. (I don't use prettier, or beautify because my company don't use these extension, so I can not use for not changing previous code by  the extensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//destructuring multi properties
const { 
foo, 
bar } = this.state;

//declaration and initialize single object
const obj = {
    foo: 'foo'
}
```

this will be more readable if you had more than one key and i think prettier will also beautify code like this.

Comment: thanks, then how about `const {foo} = this.state;` versus
`const { foo } = this.state;` which one would be better?

Answer (score 0):

- Ask your co-workers what they prefer
- Read some of your own old code - old enough that you don't remember it well - and see how you feel about it.

There is not a "best" answer to this question, and it's probably more of a topic for Reddit than SO.